# Como expandir um dois elementos simultâneamente com Javascript?

Tags: javascript, click

Preciso expandir dois elementos. Ambos tem a mesma *class* css.
O nome da *class* para expansão é `.fechado a`. Um está no elemento `.accordion-seta` e outro no `.accordion-sinal`. Seria algo igual a:

```
<div class="accordion-seta">
   <div class="fechado">
     <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
   </div>
   <div class="accordion-sinal">
       <div class="fechado">
           <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Como ficaria o Javascript desta marcação?

Sei que o código abaixo expande o primeiro.

```
document.querySelector(".accordion-seta .fechado a").click();
```

Preciso abrir os dois de uma só vez.

Comment: Como é que estás a abrir essas divs? com CSS ou JS? podes mostrar o código?

Comment: Estou abrindo com JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Troque o `querySelector` por `querySelectorAll`. O `querySelector` retorna apenas o primeiro objeto encontrado, enquanto o `querySelectorAll` retorna todos os objetos condizentes.
Em seguida, utilize o `forEach`, pra iterar entre os objetos. O `forEach` recebe uma função com um ou dois parametros: `forEach(function(element) {})` ou `forEach(function(element, index) {})`.

Nesse exemplo que eu deixei abaixo, eu utilizo apenas o `element` para realizar o `.click()`.

```
document
   .querySelectorAll('.accordion-seta .fechado a')
   .forEach(function(element) { 
      element.click(); 
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido.

```
var i = window.setInterval(expandir, 1000);
function expandir(){
    var count = $(".fechado a").length;
    document.querySelector(".fechado a").click();
    var count = $(".fechado a").length;
    if(count == 0){
        clearInterval(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: O quê esse código faz? Não consegui entender. Pensei que queria aumentar o tamanho da `div`.